# LocalStorage as a request

Tags: node.js, local-storage

How can I send the localstorage headers as a request to a node.js application?
I need to authenticate users before letting them use my application made in nodejs, but how can I access the clients' localstorage ? Can I get it as a request to the node server?

---edit---
I recently read about CORS, can that help in this situation?

Comment: I don't understand exactly: you want to access localStorage from your node server? Or you want the user to authenticate to node server before he has access to the apps' localStorage?

Comment: I want to access the localstorage from the node server.

Comment: But why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't access localStorage from the server.  You can have the browser collect all the key/value pairs in localStorage and post them to the server via AJAX, but that's about it.  localStorage is completely under client control and does not get shipped along as request headers (as cookies are).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I found this localstorage npm module for nodejs
https://npmjs.org/package/localStorage
I am able to setItem and getItem from nodejs, but if I try to get the localstorage set by another website, its storing null. Is it even possible?

Comment: When I send a request to the node server with this localstorage module, which stores an item in localstorage, I cant see anything inside localstorage on my browser. It seems this module does not actually store localstorage.

Comment: Quoting the module you're referring to: 

_This is meant for the purpose of being able to run unit-tests and such for browser-y modules in node_

LocalStorage is a client side thing, so what you're trying to do doesn't make sense. What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to make a node server which uses the authentication of another website. This node server has the access to the database of the website to authenticate the user. So if a client is already logged in into the website, he doesn't need to provide authentication for using the node server app. the website is storing the authentication details on localstorage. If i could access this item from local storage, I can authenticate the person.
Thanks for the reply

Comment: Yikes! I certainly hope that is not possible... Would be a gigantic security hole! This is something that should be handled by trust between the servers, like SSO or OAuth.

Comment: Seriously, not going to happen. You could probably change the client code to send (via XHR) the auth info to your node server.  There is not and will never be a way to access the client's localStorage from a node server.  As NilsH says, it's a terrible idea.  What you are really looking for is SSO (single sign on) support, not some localStorage hack.

Comment: What about CORS? Can it help?

Comment: No. CORS is Cross Origin Resource Sharing, not Client to Server localStorage Sharing.  Totally unrelated and not useful to you here.  I kid you not at all when i say that the only way to have localStorage content received on the server is for the client (browser) code to explicitly read it and send it (probably via AJAX) to the server.